# Typeorm lazy loading columns returns undefined

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm working with NestJS with TypeOrm.
I created `User` Entity and `Review`.
Those two entities have one to many relation. (One User can have multiple reviews)
To avoid useless join and select query, I decided to use typeorm 'lazy loading' feature.
However, when I get one Review and get its `author` column with await syntax, `author` is always `undefined` and I cannot get author data. (Besides, all other JoinColumn with lazy loading always returns undfined)

How do I get lazy loaded column properly? Am I wrong? or this situation is just bug?
I need your help.

NestJS: 10.0.0
TypeOrm: 0.3.17

Below is my code and database table.

- **review.entity.ts**

```js
import { BaseEntity } from 'src/global/base/base.entity';
import { Review } from 'src/review/entity/review.entity';
import { Column, DeleteDateColumn, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Password } from './password';

@Entity('users')
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  userId: number;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column(() => Password, { prefix: false })
  password: Password;

  @Column()
  profileImage: string;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  disabledAt: Date;

  @Column()
  refreshToken: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Review, review => review.author)
  review: Promise<Review>;

  constructor(email: string, password: Password, username: string) {
    super();
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.username = username;
  }

  public static createUser(email: string, password: Password, username: string): User {
    return new User(email, password, username);
  }
}
```

- **review.entity.ts**

```js
import { BaseEntity } from 'src/global/base/base.entity';
import { Place } from 'src/place/entity/place.entity';
import { User } from 'src/user/entity/user.entity';
import { Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { ReviewImage } from './review-image.entity';
import { ReviewStatus } from './review-status';

@Entity('place_reviews')
export class Review extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  reviewId: number;

  @Column()
  visitedAt: Date;

  @Column()
  contents: string;

  @Column({ enum: ReviewStatus })
  status: ReviewStatus;

  @Column({ type: 'float' })
  rating: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, author => author.userId, { lazy: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'author', referencedColumnName: 'userId' })
  author: Promise<User>;

  @ManyToOne(() => Place, place => place.placeId, { lazy: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'place_id', referencedColumnName: 'placeId' })
  place: Promise<Place>;

  @OneToMany(() => ReviewImage, reviewImage => reviewImage.reveiw, { lazy: true })
  images: Promise<ReviewImage[]>;

  constructor(
    visitedAt: Date,
    contents: string,
    rating: number,
    place: Promise<Place>,
    author: Promise<User>,
    images: Promise<ReviewImage[]>,
  ) {
    super();
    this.visitedAt = visitedAt;
    this.contents = contents;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.place = place;
    this.author = author;
    this.images = images;
  }

  public static createReview(
    visitedAt: Date,
    contents: string,
    rating: number,
    place: Promise<Place>,
    author: Promise<User>,
    images: Promise<ReviewImage[]>,
  ): Review {
    return new Review(visitedAt, contents, rating, place, author, images);
  }
}
```

- **my code**

```js
async validateOwner(ownerId: number, targetReviewId: number) {
  const review = await this.reviewRepository.findOneBy({ reviewId: targetReviewId });
  console.log(await review.author); // result: undefined
}
```

- **logs**
  [logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnDsR.png)
- **database (review table)**
  [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOyBg.png)

I tried to find answers from google and typeorm official docs but I couldn't solve this promblem.

Comment: await review.author() ?

Comment: @madflow no it doesn't work. review.author is not callable signature